# SSAS - named calculation

Tags: datasource, ssas, business-intelligence

Taking this into consideration that:

1. My cube's DSV reads only from views on the DW
2. I have access to create and alter these views

Lets say that I need a new field in my table CUSTOMER on the DSV witch is mapped directly to a view vwCustomer on the DW.

All the information necessary to this new field can be found on the view vwCustomer. Any advantage on creating that field as a named calculation over altering the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No advantages, only pros and cons...

Pros of adding to DSV:

1. Doesn't interfere with other applications that use vwCustomer with SELECT * queries
2. ...

Cons of adding to DSV:

1. Calculation isn't available to other applications/reports that may need to leverage it.
2. ...

that's actually all I can think of off the top.  Definitely no performance benefit to either method.  My preference would be to implement it in the view.